# How to re-enable standard C# errors in error list after uninstall?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I've noticed that ReSharper disables the standard VS2010 C# language service's error reporting to the error list.  I have to do a full build in order to get C# to provide errors that ReSharper doesn't report. When I uninstall ReSharper, C# remains in its disabled/broken state.  How can I re-enable it so that I get language service-generated errors in the error list?

Comment: I have never observed this "feature"

Comment: Which errors doesn't ReSharper report?

Comment: Invalid identifiers is the most common one I notice that C# used to recognize and underline and ReSharper never or rarely did -- and now ReSharper is uninstalled it still doesn't work (on that PC).

Answer (score 15):

> ```
> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced ->
>     "Underline errors in the editor" (check)
>     "Show live semantic errors" (check)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This hasn't happend to me. But I running `devenv.exe /reset` and maybe `devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs` once should fix the problem.

Comment: It does appear that other "hives" (i.e. experimental hive) works fine on the same box.  So it must be something in the registry and I suspect /reset would fix it.  I hesitate to try because I'd rather not lose *all* my settings.  But thanks for the tip.

Comment: You can backup all your settings an selectively restore after reset.